# the President transmits to the President pro tempore

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't quite understand the phrase "the President transmits to the President pro tempore"? Why pro tempore (which means "for the time being"), why not simply the President (of the senator)? Mike Pence is now the President of the Senate rather than the President prop tempore.  So what does the President pro tempore mean? Does it simply mean the most senior member of the Senate?

> Section 3
> Whenever **the President transmits to the President pro tempore** of the Senate and the Speaker of the House of Representatives his written declaration that he is unable to discharge the powers and duties of his office, and until he transmits to them a written declaration to the contrary, such powers and duties shall be discharged by the Vice President as Acting President.

> Source:  The 25th Amendment

Comment: This is obscure "legalese", not easy even for native speakers to understand. And I'm sure that if it comes to it, the lawyers could have a field day arguing about exactly what it means (bearing in mind that lawyers only care about whether they can *force* it to mean what their clients want; they don't care one bit about what it was *intended* to mean when actually written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question and answer probably belong on [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), but...

The [president pro tempore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_pro_tempore_of_the_United_States_Senate) is not the same as the [president of the Senate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presiding_Officer_of_the_United_States_Senate). From Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> Section Three of the United States Constitution provides that the vice president of the United States is the president of the Senate (despite not being a senator), and mandates that **the Senate must choose a president pro tempore to act in the vice president's absence**. Unlike the vice president, the president pro tempore is an elected member of the Senate, able to speak or vote on any issue.

In other words, "pro tempore" doesn't simply mean "temporary." It is a specific position defined in the U.S. Constitution. A better modern translation of what "pro tempore" means here might be "proxy," since this person acts as a proxy for the president of the Senate, i.e. a substitute who represents the president.

The current (as of 11 January 2021) president of the Senate is Vice President Mike Pence. The current president pro tempore of the Senate is [Chuck Grassley](https://www.grassley.senate.gov/). By nature of being the president pro tempore, he is third in the presidential line of succession.

Comment: If you think it belongs on a different site, you should flag for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it. Answering off-topic questions just encourages more off-topic questions.